# laravel elixir : error , module did not self-register

Tags: sass, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Since a couple of days, I can't compile sass with laravel elixir, and version it. When I run `gulp`, it gives me this error message:

```
$ gulp
[18:46:11] Using gulpfile /srv/http/xxx/gulpfile.js
[18:46:11] Starting 'default'...
[18:46:11] Starting 'sass'...
[18:46:11] 'sass' errored after 11 ms
[18:46:11] Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/http/xxx/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:211:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
Error running task sequence: { task: 'sass',
  message: 'sass catch',
  duration: 0.011248177,
  hrDuration: [ 0, 11248177 ],
  err: [Error: Module did not self-register.] }
[18:46:11] Finished 'default' after 18 ms
```

program versions:

```
$ gulp -v
[18:51:19] CLI version 3.8.11
[18:51:19] Local version 3.8.11

$ node -v
v0.12.0
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.8.8",
        "laravel-elixir": "*"
    }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass()
        .stylesIn('public/css')
        .version('css/all.css');
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `gulp-sass` which is dependency for elixir https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/152

You have one of 2 options:

- uninstall npm `v0.12.0` and install npm `v0.10.0`
- try removing your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again

Comment: removing `node_modules` and `npm install` seemed to help. it gave me some deprecation warning `Per-package engineStrict will no longer be used..` but gulp ran without problem again. thank you